# Adding Tasks to Specific Timeline Bar on Specified Timeline View

Tags: vba, ms-project

Can anyone help me develop my code so that I can use logic to capture tasks and place them on a specific timeline bar in a custom timeline view? Please see my code below. I thought this would be simple but I keep recieving a run-time error 1011.

```
Sub Machine_Loading()

Dim tsk As Task


For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks

    If tsk.ResourceNames = "Machine" Then
    
        
        Application.TaskOnTimelineEx TaskID:=tsk.ID, TimelineViewName:="Machine Utilization", BarIndex:=1 ' There are 5 different timeline bars.

    End If

Next tsk



End Sub
```

Comment: BP130. Your code runs fine for me (i.e. no error), however, the TaskOnTimelineEx  Method does not appear to be working as advertised. The BarIndex argument makes no difference, the task is seemingly put on a random bar on the specified timeline. Is the run time error you receive calling out a bad argument? If so, remember "Machine" and "machine" are different resources. You might consider adding the Option Compare Text to your code.

Comment: @john-project, it seems as if "taskontimeline" places the task on the timeline and then passes off the responsibiliy of moving the task to a specific timeline baer to the "TaskOnTimelineEx" application. I am still testing. Can I share my updated code with you?

Comment: BP130, as I noted, the BarIndex argument in the TaskOnTImelineEx" Method is not working so you still won't be able to move the task to the desired timeline (it's not the first time I found a Method that doesn't work). But, it sounds like you got past the run-time error, correct? You can post your updated code right here unless there is some reason you want to send it to me directly. In that case I'll need to give you my contact.